# Mouse scroll wheel moves window content too far each gradation

Tags: mouse, window, mouse-scroll, scrolling

On some Linux distributions, such as Ubuntu, moving the scroll wheel causes the window to move too far, usually skipping some content. It quite frustrating because it means i have to use the window slider to scroll the screen content.

Answer (score 2):

'unplugging and replugging the mouse USB connection' 
fixed this problem, in my case (UEFI windows 8 laptop). then the scrolling behaved normally. No restart, logout or window-close required. This solution comes from different problems relating to the mouse scroll wheel.

Comment: How strange - I just had a similar issue (hence visiting this question) - plugging into a different USB port fixed the problem.